# Unable to do a login redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to develop a login panel using codeigniter but I am unable to do so as I believe my concept is not so clear yet though or Am i doing something wrong please help me out with this concern

Controllers>admin.php

```
class admin extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('verify_user');
}

public function verify() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $username = $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', '', 'required|trim');
    $password = $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', '', 'required|trim');

    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->verify_user->can_log_in();
        redirect('admin/dashboard');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
}

public function dashboard() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_id') == true) {
        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
    } else {
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
}
```

models>verify_users.php

```
class verify_user extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function can_log_in() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));

        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        $query2 = $this->db->get_where('users', array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username')
        ));
        if($query2->num_rows() == 1) {
            $name  = $query2->row()->first_name . " " . $query2->row()->last_name;
        }
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {

            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username')
            ));

            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => 1
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            return true;
        } else {
            $data['message'] = 'Incorrect username/password';
            $this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is happening when I login with correct username and password it redirects me back to login.php when I put the model script within the verify function it runs perfectly

Please help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest possible fix to your way of implementation.
You need to consider reading more about MVC.
Try replace your controller with this:

```
    class admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('verify_user');
    }

    public function verify() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $username = $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', '', 'required|trim');
        $password = $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', '', 'required|trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run() && $this->verify_user->can_log_in()) {
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
    }

    public function dashboard() {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == "1") {
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
        } else {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }
}
```

And your model with this:

```
class verify_user extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function can_log_in() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));

        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        $query2 = $this->db->get_where('users', array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username')
        ));
        if($query2->num_rows() == 1) {
            $name  = $query2->row()->first_name . " " . $query2->row()->last_name;
        }
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {

            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username')
            ));

            $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => "1"
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $name);
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            return true;
        } else {
            $data['message'] = 'Incorrect username/password';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so much but please can you let me know is my process and way of logic was ok or it is a wrong approach for me

Comment: If it works then accept the answer. Read about MVC as I said. you need to put the logics in the controllers and data related functions in modes... also dashboard function seems useless.

Comment: Okay thank you and yes accepted your help and much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
class admin extends CI_Controller {
      ^// this should be Admin
```

IN model

```
else {
      //$data['message'] = 'Incorrect username/password';
      //$this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
      //dont load view in model
      return false;
 }
```

In controller

```
if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $res = $this->verify_user->can_log_in();
    if($res)
        redirect('admin/dashboard');
    else
        redirect('admin/login');
} else {
    $this->load->view('admin/login');
}
```

Fixing these 3 errors should help you.

Comment: forgot this one : `if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_id') == true) {` he is setting `'is_logged_in' => 1` in the model.